# SwiftUI переход на tabItem через кнопку

Tags: ios, swiftui

Есть ли способ перейти на Tab2 не на прямую, а через тап на красной кнопке?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            Tab1()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "star")
                    Text("Tab 1")
                }
            
            Text("Tab 2")
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "star")
                    Text("Tab 2")
                }
        }
    }
}


struct Tab1: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {}, label: {
            Text("Go to Tab2")
        })
        .padding()
        .background(Color.red)
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .cornerRadius(10)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте `TabView(selection:content:)` конструктор:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var tabIndex = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $tabIndex) {
            Tab1() {
                tabIndex = 1
            }
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "star")
                Text("Tab 1")
            }
            .tag(0)
            
            Text("Tab 2")
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "star")
                    Text("Tab 2")
                }
                .tag(1)
        }
    }
}


struct Tab1: View {
    let action: () -> Void
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: action, label: {
            Text("Go to Tab2")
        })
        .padding()
        .background(Color.red)
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .cornerRadius(10)
    }
}
```